# Split Dataframes into 2 columns and merge into original

Tags: python, dataframe, split

I am trying to split a dataframe column into two columns and have it "merged" into the original one. For example, some players have multiple position eligibility and I want to split them into a primary and secondary position column.

Player     Roster Position
John Doe      1B/2B

Becomes 
Player     Primary Position       Secondary Position
John Doe      1B                        2B

The code is as follows - I tried a merge and of course it is telling me that there are no like columns to merge on. I don't know if I can merge based on the index, or how to get the player name to go into the "secondData" dataframe.

```
filename = "DKSalaries.csv"

playerData = pd.read_csv(filename)


secondData = (playerData['RosterPosition'].str.split('/', 1, expand=True).rename(columns={0:'Primary Position', 1:'Secondary Position'}))

newData = playerData.merge(secondData, how='left')
print(newData)
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE].

Comment: Essentially, I'm trying to take 1 dataframe with a column that needs to be split. For example - the column "RosterPosition" comes through like this - 1B/2B.......I want to take that column and make two new ones - primary position and secondary position. The 1B would go in the primary column and the 2B would go in the secondary column. Currently my code is working up until the merge - the secondData only gives an index column and then the primary and secondary column that I told it to create. I want to merge this into the original dataframe if that helps. Can I attach a csv file?

Comment: Why are you describing your data to me instead of pasting a [mcve] with 5-10 rows of your data in a reproducible, understandable example in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To merge on index use:

```
playerData.merge(secondData, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: That does exactly what I need it to do so thank you so much. However, I'm still kind of questioning is there a way to bring the player names into the secondData, or is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?